# NUnit и VS2015. Управление пакетами NuGet. Visual Studio для нового решения/проекта требует загрузку NUnit заново.

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nunit

Добрый вечер!

У меня есть одна проблема с пакетами NuGet. Допустим, я создал проект, для него подгрузил пакет NUnit. Он работает и все хорошо. **НО!** Когда я создаю новый проект и хочу использовать NUnit Framework, то менеджер пакетов NuGet не видит установленного пакета NUnit и мне приходится заново скачивать этот пакет из интернета, и так для каждого нового проекта. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: А проекты вы создаете в одном и том же решении (Solution)?

Comment: @Bulson могу в том же решении, могу в другом. Я понимаю, что можно сразу для решения подгрузить пакет NUnit. А можно ли как-то его подгрузить таким образом, чтобы его не приходилось скачивать постоянно при создании нового решения и при этом не помещая его вручную в GAC?

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема-то? NUnit - сторонний пакет (зависимость). Новый проект требует установки всех зависимостей. Это нормально. Или вы хотите, чтобы зависимости подгружались сами (как при добавлении EF)?

Comment: @klutch1991 я не считаю это нормальным, когда ты каждый раз должен **скачивать** пакет заново, когда он есть в другом решении скаченный. Разве Microsoft не позаботилась о том, чтобы скачанные пакеты попадали в какую-нибудь специальную папку Visual Studio типа "Downloaded Packages" и при необходимости VS бы оттуда копировала этот пакет в наше решение по нажатии кнопки какой-нибудь?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а его и не нужно скачивать, nuget его находит в кеше

Answer (score 0):

Создайте шаблон NUnit, как это описано на сайте Microsoft:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit

**1.** Установка шаблона проекта NUnit (при этом скачаются оба пакета - NUnit и NUnit3TestAdapter)
Перед созданием тестового проекта необходимо установить шаблоны тестовых проектов NUnit. Это действие необходимо выполнить только один раз на каждом компьютере разработчика, где создаются новые проекты NUnit. Для установки шаблонов NUnit выполните **dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template**

**2.** Используйте шаблон (в каталоге проекта введите команду **dotnet new nunit**)

Перейдите в каталог PrimeService.Tests и создайте проект с помощью dotnet new nunit. Команда dotnet new создает тестовый проект, который использует NUnit в качестве библиотеки тестов. Созданный шаблон настраивает средство запуска тестов в файле PrimeServiceTests.csproj:

Собственно, все. Далее наслаждаемся жизнью и отладкой.