# Копирование нативных библиотек в выходную папку

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Есть решение (solution) с двумя проектами: первый — библиотека, второй — запускаемое приложение.

Во второй проект добавлена ссылка на первый.

В первый проект добавлен nuget-пакет, в котором есть какие-то нативные библиотеки.

Проблема: при сборке проекта, эти нативные библиотеки не копируются в выходную папку ВТОРОГО проекта.

В выходной папке первого проекта эти библиотеки есть, если их скопировать в выходную папку второго проекта вручную, приложение работает нормально.

Как сделать так, чтобы все библиотеки копировались автоматически?

Comment: Установит тот же nuget на втором проекте

Comment: нугет сторонний или мейнтейнится вами на своём сборочном сервере?

Comment: Ну вроде по описанию это давнишняя [проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol) студии

Comment: @DIlshod, второй проект напрямую не использует этот пакет, зачем ему такая зависимость? В первом проекте вполне может измениться реализация и от этого nuget-пакета может быть в дальнейшем откажусь. Либо я буду использовать первый проект еще в 10 других солюшенах, мне в них все добавлять зависимость?

Comment: @AK, из NuGet.org

Comment: @Vasek там описывается *другая* проблема.

Comment: Есть еще вариант, скинуть оба проекта на один Output

Comment: Друзья, у меня был схожий вопрос с пакетами NuGet (не такой же, но похожий). [Вот он.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644146/212981) Я так и не смог найти решения для себя, кроме как вручную копировать скачанные пакеты NuGet. А то у меня было такое дело, что приходилось создавать много солюшенов и каждый раз приходилось грузить пакет из интернета заново.

Comment: Как по мне, так полезный ответ, для SO во всяком случае, можно бы и галку поставить. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Тут есть две проблемы, и первая из них - кривые руки автора пакета. Частенько в подобных пакетах копирование файлов в выходную папку делается каким-то велосипедом, который, конечно же, стандартным тулчейном не распознается.

Вам нужно найти внутри nuget-пакета targets-файл, изучить его структуру и написать свой патч. Стандартную цель придется отключить, и написать свою.

Идея в том, что любой файл, копируемый в выходную папку, должен копироваться стандартным тулчейном. Для этого требуется "повеситься" на `AssignTargetPaths` и создать по элементу `ContentWithTargetPath` на каждый копируемый файл:

```
<Target Name="КакойтоГлупыйТаргетИзПакета" />
<Target Name="AssignLibPaths" AfterTargets="AssignTargetPaths">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ContentWithTargetPath Include="$(КакоетоСвойствоИзПакета)\lib\foo.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <TargetPath>foo.dll</TargetPath>
        </ContentWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Все элементы, добавленные таким образом, будут копироваться в зависимые проекты (точно так же, как копируются файлы, отмеченные как `CopyToOutputDirectory=PreserveNewest`).

Отмечу на всякий случай, что загруженные через nuget файлы редактировать не имеет смысла, все изменения должны вноситься непосредственно в ваш файл проекта (`.csproj`). Подробное описание синтаксиса выходит за рамки ответа, ищите информацию по ключевому слову "msbuild".

---

Отдельного упоминания заслуживают пакеты, которые вовсе вместо расширения сборки при установке просто добавляют команды xcopy в PostBuildEvent.

Эти команды xcopy следует оттуда вычистить, и заменить на особый Target.

Как вариант, вы можете просто добавить все нужные файлы в проект как ссылки - хуже уже не будет.

---

Вторая проблема - в транзитивных зависимостях. Если проект А зависит от Б, а Б зависит от С - то файлы из проекта А не попадут в проект С. Эту проблему MS решать даже не пытались (более того, у меня есть подозрение что так сделано намеренно - потому что компилятор C# тоже не поддерживает транзитивные зависимости!).

Проблема возникает из-за того, что цель `_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence`, ответственная за получение списка зависимых проектов, ожидает элементов, определенных целью `AssignProjectConfiguration` - но никогда явно не требует её.

Так давайте это исправим!

```
<Target Name="FixCopyItemsFromSubsubprojects"
        DependsOnTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" 
        BeforeTargets="_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence"
/>
```

Сам я так ни разу не делал, так что всех последствий такого решения не скажу.

Comment: @АндрейNOP в файле проекта (csproj). Его можно открыть в любом XML-редакторе. Можно даже в самой студии, только перед этим придется выгрузить.

Comment: @АндрейNOP это как-то мешает вам добавить свои?