# Nuget-пакет с логикой установки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Вот у меня есть пакет, который зависит от нативных сборок.
После того, как пакет установлен и подключен, для корректной работы программы, нативный сборки должны копировать в директорию со скомпилированной программой.

Подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему? Чтобы в добавляемом проекте, например, создавались папки с этими необходимыми сборками, которые будут копировать при каждом билде.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972865/218063