# Почему при подстановке собранного пакета вместо установленного из nuget.org некорректно работают ссылки?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, properties

Речь идет о пакетах C# (nuget)
Проблема следующая: есть проект A, который зависит от пакета B, пакет B в свою очередь зависит от пакета C. (A <- B <- C). Я собираю своими руками из исходников пакет C и подставляю его в проекты. Проект D (другой), который напрямую ссылается на C, может корректно использовать API пакета C. В то время как в проекте A, все ссылки рода B.C не работают, а ссылки рода A.C работают, если сослаться напрямую на пакет C, но это все еще не решает нерабочих ссылок B.C
Пакет собирался скриптом, написанным авторами пакета
Мне нужно хотя бы понять, куда копать...

Comment: Возможно кривые nuget'ы? Типа как описано в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972865/213987

Comment: @AK посмотрел и еще почитаю, но тут проблема не совсем такая же, под dotPeek сборки идентичные и никакие нативные либы не копируются(

Comment: Скорее всего, пакет B при разрешении зависимостей ищет пакет C в источниках NuGet пакетов, т.е. он не знает ничего о том, что у Вас в решении имеется собранный в ручную пакет C и не может на него ссылаться. И мне кажется, что у Вас в вопросе в некоторых местах путаются понятия "пакет" и "проект". Может поможет сборка пакета B (из исходников), по аналогии с проектом С? Или pre-build задача, которая бы выполняла сборку проекта C в пакет С и размещала его в локальном хранилище пакетов NuGet, который в свою очередь был бы указан в качестве источника пакетов NuGet?

Comment: Если пакету B нужен пакет C, то при установке пакета B установится и пакет C. Я не совсем понимаю, что имеется ввиду под `ссылка рода A.C(рабочая) и B.C(не рабочая)`.

Comment: @XelaNimed вроде не путал пакет и проект, Ваши идеи попробую

Comment: @AndreiKhotko имеется ввиду, что не собранный мною пакет B, ссылающийся на  собранный мною пакет C работает некорректно, якобы нет никакого пакета C. А мой проект A, ссылающийся на пакет C вполне корректно использует API пакета C. Для лучшего понимания представим, что у пакета B есть некий класс Token со свойством Json (свойство определено в C). Тогда в проекте A следующая ссылка не будет работать: var t = new Token(); t.Json = null; А эта будет: var j = new Json();

Comment: @XelaNimed предложенный вариант с pre-build как раз и используется, в качестве --source указываю локальную папку

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, указанная локальная папка используется для разрешения зависимостей NuGet пакетов, или?

Comment: Как вы подключаете нугет-пакет `C` в проектах `A` и `B`? Какой версии фреймворков и библиотек вы пользуетесь в каждом проекте?

Comment: @XelaNimed верно

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я его для них не подключаю, пакет B был скачан, он ссылается на пакет C через PackageReference. Если говорить о примере, когда я пробую использовать напрямую пакет C в проекте A, то я делаю аналогичное, использую PackageReference. Фреймворк использую netcoreapp3.1. Версии библиотек не имеют значения, сорцы я скачивал правильных версий

Comment: Чудес на свете не бывает. Значит при разрешении зависимостей NuGet пакета собранный Вами пакет не подхватывается.

Comment: @Олег вы можете контролировать сборку пакета `B`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки выяснилось, что не было никаких проблем с nuget, комментарий @XelaNimed помог. Надо было собирать пакет правильно, какие-то конфиги ломают его и несмотря на внешнюю работоспособность nuget во время восстановления не подхватывает его